# Using special characters with string replace

Tags: javascript

I need to use the ) key in string.replace but since it is used in coding it breaks the code, I've tried using some special codes like &#x0000 and %00 (examples) but none of them have worked I don't know what this is called so I can't search it up.

```js
fullstring = fullstring.replace(/:)/g,"")
```

) breaks code

Comment: have you tried using the `\` escape character before your `)` - e.g., `/\:\)/g`?

Comment: : isn't a special character.
should i do (/:\)/g,"")

Comment: Try `'Hello :)'.replace(/:\)/g,"")`

Comment: thanks fixed, i know this is such a small thing but I have been searching for about an hour

Comment: @Luke why not test in https://regex101.com first :-D

Comment: @xdeepakv see that's the thing i didn't know what it's called or what to search, but ill use that in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpliest way would be:

```js
console.log('You are :) like a boss. Life is good :)'.replace(/:\)/g,""))
```

You should use `\` escape character before `)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an escape character to get around the parentheses and colon. For example:

`fullstring = fullstring.replace(/:\)/g,"")`

More info on escaping special characters [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping)